# Scale Android Path

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, android-canvas

I am using a Path to draw a function to the Canvas. The problem I am facing is that the function is not scaled in the x axis. I tried using Canvas.sacale() in the onDraw() method but it made the path drawing blur. How can I stretch the path drawing in the x axis with out the blur.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to scale the `Canvas` it will blur as if it is a bitmap. You should use some property from animation geometry to scale the `Path`.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
RectF rectF = new RectF();
your_path.computeBounds(rectF, true);
matrix.setScale(1.25f, 1f or 0f, rectF.centerX(), rectF.centerY());
your_path.transform(matrix);
```

Comment: DO i have to call this in onDraw()?

Comment: Yes, if that's the case.

Comment: Do you hold the reference of path outside the canvas. If yes then try setting from outside the canvas. But I doubt. This works as I am using but not with canvas.

Comment: Tried, still does not work. I basically have a sine graph that draws 21 peeks, I have to spread it to 10 or11